# Remove facebook HipHop (hhvm) Ubuntu and debug it

Tags: facebook, ubuntu, hiphop, hhvm

I have installed hhvm by using the building and installing hhvm in Ubuntu 13.10 from GitHub and now I want to uninstall it from my system completely. I am not getting any documentation regarding this.

I am uninstalling because I am not able to make a server using:

```
hhvm -m server -p 8080` nor ` hhvm -m server -vServer.Type=fastcgi -vServer.Port=8080
```

It is giving error like

> WARNING: Logging before InitGoogleLogging() is written to STDERR
>   E0321 17:09:56.491703 13532 fastcgi-session.cpp:562] FastCGI protocol: received an invalid record

Comment: I get the same error using the prebuilt package for 12.04. This is with:

    hhvm --version
    HipHop VM 2.4.2 (rel)
    Compiler: tags/HHVM-2.4.2-0g432ecffa04b21c60953bb236a9db8278f4650537
Repo schema: 1be260b29a71097b5d1f78c6e4dcbb981ba03bde

and Apache/2.4.7

Answer (score 12):

Run

```
sudo /usr/share/hhvm/uninstall_fastcgi.sh
```

the run

```
sudo apt-get remove hhvm
```

then restart your server(nginx/apache)

Answer (score -1):

Hopefully (not tested) hhvm supports the `make uninstall` action assuming you have built from souce (you mention github so its a safe bet)

In the directory you ran `make` try running `make uninstall`